# Detecting Uninitialised memory reads in c++(GCC compiler)

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am using a python script to call functions from c++ shared libraries using ctypes. I want to detect uninitialised memory reads while the code is running(dynamically). Also, it should be as quick as possible. I've tried Valgrind but it is quite slow. With Clang compiler Memory sanitisers work great but I am using GCC compiler.

I've tried Valgrind and ASan. ASan could not detect uninitialised memory while Valgrind comes with 20-30 times slowdown. Is there any possible way to detect these errors with a lower slowdown

Comment: gcc has an address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`).

Comment: There are a few different sanitizers, you can try to play around with some of them (clang and gcc both have some build in, and there are also some standalone). But fundamentally it is going to be slow to detect uninitialized memory errors: You have to tag every bit of memory that is allocated, then you have to add instructions before every write to poke the tag, and before every read to make sure that the tag has been poked. This is just going to be slow no matter what, compared to "normal" memory access.

Comment: -fsanitize=address can't detect memory corruption and there is no memory sanitizer for gcc(ie. -fsanitize=memory for clang).